# problem with expander control in publishing

Tags: wpf

I have expander control that it works in vs and blend correctly but when i build a setup file and executed it cant work correctly.(does it work correctly in win xp?)

Comment: What does "it can't work correctly" mean? what happens? Are you getting an error? Does it just not look right? Can you post screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on Windows XP. But you should install latest updates for .net framework.

Comment: .net framework 4.o is installed.
but expander works correctly in win7 and works not correctly in xp. in xp .net framework 4.0 is installed.

Comment: It's possible to have installed .net 4.0 and not installed latest updates for .net 3.5. What exactly doesn't work?